# Find and remove apostrophe and one letter before?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, url, slug

The goal is to clean up a character string and delete elements not important for the user and SEO ie the (letter before the apostrophes) in my case. I would mainly like a solution or an explanation of a regex that would do that in PHP but the logic is no different in JS.

character string : .../mod**e-d'e**mploi/...

Become:

url: /mod**e-e**mploi/slug-34

Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Consider looking into `String.prototype.replace` and Regular Expressions.

Comment: Using Javascript or PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split with the apostrophe and then remove the last character of the first splitted string so that it simulates the removal of character just before apostrophe:

```js
var url = "/mode-d'emploi/slug-34";

var resArray = url.split("\'");
resArray[0] = resArray[0].substring(0, resArray[0].length - 1);
var res = resArray.join('');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This removes any character before an apostrophe and the apostrophe.

```js
var url = "/mode-d'emploi/slug-34";
res = url.replace(/.'/, '');
console.log(res);
```

If you want to remove a letter only, use:

```js
var url = "/mode-d'emploi/slug-34";
res = url.replace(/[a-z]'/i, '');
console.log(res);
```